# If $64$ is divided into three parts proportional to $2$, $4$ and $6$, what is the smallest part?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

If $64$ is divided into three parts proportional to $2$, $4$ and $6$, what is the smallest part?

The problem I have is with understanding what the question means.

What does it mean for a number $N$ to be divided into $n$-parts proportional to $x_1,...,x_n$? Is it like this means that there exist constants $\xi_1,...,\xi_2$ such that $$N=x_1\xi_1+x_2\xi_2+...+x_{n-1}\xi_{n-1}+x_n\xi_n$$ or that for a single constant $\xi$ we have $$N=x_1\xi+...+x_n\xi=\xi(x_1+...+x_n)?.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number $N$ is divided into $n$ parts proportional to $x_1, \dots, x_n$, I would imagine that means

$$N= a_1+\cdots + a_n$$
such that $a_1:a_2:\dots:a_n = x_1:x_2:\dots:x_n$ or in other words, there exists such a positive constant $\lambda$ that $a_1=\lambda x_1$, $a_2=\lambda x_2,\dots, a_n = \lambda x_n$.

Comment: so my second proposition is true?

Comment: @user153330 It is my feeling. It is not crystal clear, but it seems that your second proposition fits the question.

Comment: @user153330 Yes. The first is too loose, i.e. any set of numbers that sum to $N$ can be represented as $a_i=x_i\xi_i$ if you can select $n$ different values of $\xi_i$

Comment: in the example $$64=2\xi+4\xi+6\xi\implies\xi=\frac{64}{12}=\frac{32}{6}=\frac{16}{3},$$ the smallest part will be the one will the smallest coeff. which is 2, so the smallest part is $\frac{32}{3}$ ?

Comment: Correct. As far as I understand the question, you answered it fully.

Comment: @5xum ok, thanks : )